# does being battered build muscle?

Tags: human-anatomy, human-physiology, muscles

My crude understanding of how people normally go about building muscle is something like this following 2 step process:

1) a person can lift weights (for example), which tears muscle and stimulates the nervous system.
2) They can then eat protein and get sleep, which build the muscle back up stronger than it was before, as the nervous system tells the body that more muscle is needed to handle the type of stimulation its been getting.

Now to my question: exotic training techniques like EMS exist which do the same in principle as lifting weights.  What about something as simple as the muscles taking a beating (as in kickboxing)?  If a muscle is battered in a systematic way, will it be built up stronger as per the muscle building process?  If so, what type of muscle would this be (Fast twitch/slow)?  Would it transfer well to overall strength?